Colorbar in Nilearn glassbrain plotting appears greyed out
I would like to depict my data in glassbrain visualization using Nilearn's plotting.plot_glass_brain function. My data ranges from -11 to +4.5 and I would like those values to be my minimum/maximum value shown on the colorbar. The correct numbers are shown, however, the bottom part (between -4.5 and -11) is greyed out and values lying in this range are depicted with the color of -4.5 instead, as the colorbar somehow ends here. How can I get rid of this greyed out area and extent the colorbar to -11?
colorbar shows grey area
This is the code I used:
display=plotting.plot_glass_brain(imgavg, output_file=outputfile, cmap=colormap, colorbar=True, display_mode='lyrz', vmax=vmax, vmin=vmin, plot_abs=False, symmetric_cbar=False, threshold=None)
I thought by setting plot_abs=False, symmetric_cbar=False, and threshold=None the colorbar should appear correctly. It seems like some thresholding is still applied even though I set it to 'None'?
